# Как посмотреть тайминги оперативной памяти на Ubuntu?

Tags: тайминги, ubuntu

-

Comment: прямо из консоли, удаленно

Answer (score 1):

System Load Indicator  Системный монитор способен отображать графики загрузки процессора, памяти, файла подкачки и сетевого трафика.

Answer (score 0):

[ICS PLL tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icspll/)